# Typing a functional component react using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to change this anon. function

```js
const Button: React.FunctionComponent = ({ children }: Props) => { })
```

to function signature

```js
function Button() { }
```

But how can I insert the type `React.FunctionComponent` on function version?

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this:

```
interface DummyProps{
property1:string //here instead of property1 you can name it whatever you want to and its type can be anything.For example i have used here string
}

export default ({property1}:DummyProps) => {
return (
       <div>
           {property1}
       </div>
   );
}
```